# Cast Error while calling modal.countDocuments() & modal.count() in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**My Mongoose Function**

Error Message: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "count" at path "_id" for model "myinfo""

```js
exports.indexCount = function(req, res) {
 MyInfo.countDocuments({}, function(err, count) { 
  if (err) {
   res.json({
    status: "error",
    message: err,
   });
  }
  console.log("Number of users:", count);
  res.json({
   status: "success",
   message: "Count info retrieved successfully",
   data: count,
  });
 });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem was with my route**

1. Since i already have a route "/myinfo/:id". my mistake was i am using
   "/myinfo/count" route for getting count values which is wrong.
   because count is mapped as :id in my above route
2. i changed the "/myinfo/count" to "/myinfo/get/count" it works now.

Comment: Hey I was facing the same issue and your technique helped me resolved that. But still, I'm not able to figure out why it was not working when I had route as ```/blogs/count``` but started working fine when I changed it to ```/blogs/get/count```. Also, I wanna know that do I always have to use ```get``` in the route or can I use any other keyword too?